# How to get only sharp hours in joda-time

Tags: java, datetime, arraylist, time, jodatime

lets say we have a DateTime ArrayList that contains a full date formatted yyyyMMddHHmmss

```
ArrayList<DateTime> dt = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
dt.add("20160418220000");
dt.add("20160418213000");
dt.add("20160418210000");
dt.add("20160418203000");
```

How do I print only the sharp hours (like 22:00) in joda-time?

Comment: Your code does not compile. What do you want to hold in your list? Strings or `DateTime`? Otherwise using a property manipulation will probably help: [hourOfDay.roundFloorCopy()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html#roundFloorCopy--)

Comment: @MenoHochschild the code is just an example, and I want to hold `DateTime` in the list and compare it with another list, and only return times at the sharp hour

Comment: Are you sure about a given format? It looks more like `yyyMMddHHmmss`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I am sorry about that, I've edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property of field `hourOfDay` to apply a [floor-manipulation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html#roundFloorCopy--):

```
List<DateTime> dtListOld = dt; // your input
List<DateTime> dtListNew = new ArrayList<>();

for (DateTime dateTime : dtListOld) {
  dtListNew.add(dateTime.hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy());
}
```

These lists hold `DateTime`-objects according to your comment above. For further processing like formatting, you can use `DateTimeFormatter`. For comparisons with other unrounded instances of `DateTime`, you can use the usual comparing methods like `isEqual()` (strict test for same instant at sharp hours).

Please be aware of the fact that testing for strict equality of date-times (instants) at sharp hours can be errorprone if the source of date-time-objects is a clock (which usually produces millisecond-fractions). In that case, you could apply a similar rounding mode to the other objects to be compared to (but maybe on minute or second base).

**Comparison example:**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime other1 = dtf.parseDateTime("20160418184137");
DateTime other2 = dtf.parseDateTime("20160418180000");

DateTime sharpHour = now.hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy();

if (!sharpHour.isEqual(other1.minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy())) {
    System.out.println("Not matching sharp hour: " + other1);
}
DateTime other2Floor = other2.minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy();
if (sharpHour.isEqual(other2Floor)) {
    System.out.println("Matching sharp hour: " + other2);
}
```

Output:

> Not matching sharp hour: 2016-04-18T18:41:37.000+02:00
>
> Matching sharp hour: 2016-04-18T18:00:00.000+02:00

The usage of floored rounding makes sure that you don't forget the parts whose precision is higher than needed. For example, a query/condition like `getMinuteOfHour() == 0` would not take into account possible seconds or milliseconds deviating from zero.

Comment: This is really interesting! but how could you use roundFloorCopy() for in an if statement or for comparison?

Comment: This is very helpful and just what I was looking for, Thanks heaps!